# Choose the correct element from the list of objects with the same className

Tags: selenium

Quick one, i am trying to avoid using xpath and using css selectors due to performance issues xpath can have so i would like to know the right approach of locating for example "A" in the list

```
<div class="input-search-suggests" xpath="1">
<div class="input-search-suggests-item">A</div>
<div class="input-search-suggests-item">B</div>
<div class="input-search-suggests-item">C</div>
</div>
```

Currently i am locating A using xpath / span but it would be indeed sufficient locating all elements and then grabbing A from the list that have same class which is "input-search-suggests-item"

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'A')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSS_SELECTOR` `does not have support` for direct `text` what `xpath has`.

What this means is, for the below `xpath`

```
xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'A')]"
```

based on text `A` you **can not** write a `css selector`.

Instead to locate `A` using css selector, you can do :

```
div.input-search-suggests > div.input-search-suggests-item
```

In **Selenium** something like this :

```
@FindBy(cssSelector= "div.input-search-suggests > div.input-search-suggests-item")
```

Even though it will have `3 matching nodes`, but `findElement` will take the **first web element**.

Also you may wanna look at `nth-child(n)`

```
div.input-search-suggests > nth-child(1)
```

to make use of index to locate `A, B, C`

Here is the [Reference Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you brother so much, this is very clear and if there will be two elements i would need to specify the element index right ? [1] [2]

Comment: Yes please follow the reference link in the solution attached, there are more things you can do with css selectors.